# How to use cell background image which has height more than the cell height?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, custom-cell

I am facing a problem to display cell selected image with the height, which is higher than the cell height.

Here is the sample:

[image]

So here, my cell height is 44 but the selected cell background image height is 50.

I have tried to set the cell selected background image and also by adding new image view to cell as subview. But the doing so that cell getting selected and image is getting scale to fill with the size of cell height. So that arrow appears inside the cell and image gets squeezed.

Second methodology with I tried was separating the arrow image using a button, but that option also not worked for me.
If I go with this methodology, than that button is not getting displayed. Here, I think that part is getting overlapped by the next row of the table view.

Please suggest me how to solve this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you can resize the cell or the set the image view into the custom cell.

Comment: No, cell size required to be same, check the image shown along with question. If i change the cell height than the person image and name alignment again looks odd. Can't we overlap the next cell anyhow?

Comment: resize that particular image to height 44

Comment: Solved that issue. Please find the added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your responses. I have solve that problem and the code is here:

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
        reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
      self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

      if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        [self setClipsToBounds:NO];

       // selected background image view
        if (self.selectedBgImageView == nil) {

    //     w 302  :  h 50
          self.selectedBgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                      initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -5, 302, 50)];
        }
      [self.selectedBgImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];    
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.selectedBgImageView];
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

  // Configure the view for the selected state

  // child count label
  [self.childCountLabel setBackgroundColor:
    [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_contacts_network_total"]]];

  // selected background image view
  if (self.indentationLevel % 2 == 0) {

    [self.selectedBgImageView setImage:
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_contacts_network_expand_box_tier1"]];
  }
  else {

    [self.selectedBgImageView setImage:
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"img_contacts_network_expand_box_tier2"]];
  }

  [self.selectedBgImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
//  [self.con:selectedBgImageView];
}
```

There I found that setting frame was a problem, i don't know the reason for such odd calculation for frame origin. But somehow it worked for me and it worked perfectly as per requirement.

If anyone knows reason behind this behavior please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can play with `Clip Subviews` property of cells or actual table.
You just put your `UIImageView` into the cell (not sure if you could assign it as Background property but you can try) and set it's height bigger than the cell height. But the only issue is that you could experience images overlapping. You can try to resolve it by setting the actual index where to put your view for selected state.

Well, tested a bit. Look at this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId] autorelease];
        cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        CGRect frame = cell.bounds;
        UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBackground"];
        cell.backgroundView = background;
        [background release];

        frame.size.height = 50.0;
        UIImageView *selected = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        selected.tag = 13;
        selected.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellSelectedBackground"];
        [cell insertSubview:selected atIndex:1];
        selected.hidden = YES;
        [selected release];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The main things here is `cell.clipsToBounds = NO;` and `[cell insertSubview:selected atIndex:1];`. But it'll be much better to create subclass for the cell and handle all stuff and selection here. Though as seen at your pic you're using subclassed cells already :)